# How to count raw characters in a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to count the actual characters in a string regardless of their meaning.
In example, `\n` I want to count slash (`\` and `n`) == 2 characters and not as a `<EOL>` = 1

So a string like `a\nb` will equal `4` and not `3`

Details
(1) \n

```
var a = `a
b`;

console.log(a.length)
>>> 3
```

But in python

```
>>> a = r'a\nb'
>>> len(a)
4
```

(2) smart-quotes
Javascript

```
var a = 'a“b';
console.log(a.length);
>>> 3
```

Python

```
>>> b = 'a“b'
>>> len(b)
5
```

I've tried many functions ( like braking the string to array, but `\n` is in a single cell )

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can't count escape characters in a string. If you have a string literal with `\t` it is compiled identically to a string with a literal tab character, for example.

Comment: There isn't a slash character in the *string*. It only appears in the JavaScript source code.

Comment: Consider two strings, "\u00e6" and "æ".  These are identical strings.  Once defined, there is no way to reverse the process.  See: http://jsbin.com/mubajuf/edit?html,output

Comment: _Regular Python strings are *not* unicode, they are just plain bytes._ So `“` is three _bytes_ long but 1 character long.

Comment: @SalmanA I understand what all above are saying, but  my backend and front-end word counting do not match ... and I just can't believe there's no solution out there, this is why I created this thread ..

Comment: You can do `String.raw\`a\nb\`.length` (same way like Python's r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've tried to answer in the comment but it wasn't pleasant to read.

The issue is split in two major problems:

- counting raw chars
- counting ASCII length instead of UTF-16 one

I will answer to both issues with examples.

**counting raw chars**

The only way to consider '\n' string as two chars with one backslash and one `n` letter, is to use a function tag and a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
const rawlength = tpl => tpl.raw.join('').length;

`a\nb`.length;   // 3
rawlength`a\nb`; // 4
```

You can copy and paste above code and read the two different results. Bear in mind, not using parenthesis with `rawlength` is not a typo, but how template literals work.

Also bear in mind if you use a template literal like the following one

```
`a
b`
```

its length will still be 3 because there is indeed no backslash in there, so the `\n` char is considered one char as it should be.

In Python, that would be equivalent

```
len("""a
b""")
```

That' a 3.

**Edit: the Python `r` in JavaScript**

The equivalent of `r` in JavaScript would be:

```
const r = (t, ...v) => {
  const result = [t.raw[0]];
  const length = t.length;
  for (let i = 1; i < length; i++)
    result.push(v[i - 1], t.raw[i]);
  return result.join('');
};
```

So that:

```
r`a\nb`
```

Would produce what you expect.

You can add the following trick around `result.join('')` to also have the length as ASCII/bytes instead.

**counting ASCII length instead of UTF-16 one**

This is an old trick to always count bytes:

```
unescape(encodeURIComponent('a“b')).length;
```

That's a `5`, because `encodeURIComponent` would return an UTF-8 url friendly version of the text, and `unescape` will create a char per each `%XX` encountered.

In this case `'a“b'` becomes `a%E2%80%9Cb` which is `ab` plus 3 url encoded chars.

Comment: so `rawlength\`a\nb\`; // 4` is exactly what I need, problem, is, it's inside a variable :/ so how do I run this with variable `a` ?

Comment: Like in Python, where you need to use `r` upfront (which I've edited in my answer so it's clear how to do that in JS too), if you assign `s = 'a\nb'` that already gets translated into 3 chars string so you either use template literal tag at definition time, or you are out of luck 'cause escaped chars are translated, same as `\x27` is a quote in JS, not a 4 length string, `\n` and others are no different. However, if you literally write `a\nb` in an input field, that arrives already as 4 length string so I'm not sure what's your issue.

Comment: I'll mark the answer, as the `r` is a helpful match just like coding in Python `r` ... and I understand what you were trying to say now ! thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Did you try replace the `\n` to a double countable character? Something like:

`'a\nb'.replace('\n', '--').length # return 4`

Comment: not exactly, because `\n` was just an example, it can be any hidden character outthere ... and I don't want to map them manually in code